# Need to label data ouput

Tags: php, html

I am trying to extract data from a table and display it in a readable format. The table has 15 columns.  I can do it horizontally, but it is hard to read that way. I have figured out how to get the data to come out vertical but I can not figure out how to label each row. It would even work if I could print the column name with the data.  Below is my query:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM DailyNumber WHERE location='Discount25'"); 
$post = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $post[] = $row;
    }
     foreach ($post as $row) 
        { 
            foreach ($row as $element)
            {
                echo $element."<br>";
            }        
        }     
?>
```

Output

```
     Discount25
     2014-03-03 
     1
     2 
     4
     5
     6 
     7 
     8 
     9 
     1 
     2 
     3 
     4
```

It would output like something like this:

```
     Location:      Discount25
     DAte:          2014-03-03
     Sales:         1
     Gross Profit:  2
     Expenses:      3
     Cat 1:         4
     Cat 2:         5
    etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$row as $key => $value` and then place it into a neat little table.

```
echo '<table>';

foreach ($post as $row) 
{ 
    foreach ($row as $key => $value)
    {
        echo ' <tr><th> ' . $key . ' </th><td> ' . $value . ' </td></tr> ';
    }        
}

echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$key => $value`:

```
foreach ($post as $row) 
{ 
    foreach ($row as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key . ' - '. $value . '<br />';
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to extract keys as well in your iteration and print them out

```
 foreach ($post as $row) 
 { 
    foreach ($row as $key => $element)
    {
        echo $key . ': '. $element."<br>";
    }        
}
```